# Get Attribute Value From Specific Select Option

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

How can I access attribute value in a option, when I choose it?

This my HTML

```
<select name="property_id">
   <option value="1" price="15000">Property A</option>
   <option value="2" price="21000">Property B</option>
</select>
```

And this is my JS

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $price      = $(this).attr('price'),
        $percentage = $("input[name='participation_percent']").on("input", calculatePrice),
        $discount   = $("input[name='participation_amount']").on("input", calculatePerc);

    function calculatePrice() {
        var percentage = $(this).val();
        var price      = $price.val();
        var calcPrice  = ( price * percentage / 100 ).toFixed(2);
        $discount.val( calcPrice );
    }

    function calculatePerc() {
        var discount = $(this).val();
        var price    = $price.val();
        var calcPerc = (discount * 100 / price);
        $percentage.val( calcPerc );
    }
</script>
```

I want get value from attribute price, but it's not working.
Any idea ?

Comment: using this context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chosen option will be send to the console with every change. You can also just store it in some variable for future use.

Added code: `$("#select").val()`.

**Note**: You didn't specify which exact value do you expect to be shown, so I'm adding two cases - `value` and `price`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $price = $(this).attr('price'),
    $percentage = $("input[name='participation_percent']").on("input", calculatePrice),
    $discount = $("input[name='participation_amount']").on("input", calculatePerc);

  function calculatePrice() {
    var percentage = $(this).val();
    var price = $price.val();
    var calcPrice = (price * percentage / 100).toFixed(2);
    $discount.val(calcPrice);
  }

  function calculatePerc() {
    var discount = $(this).val();
    var price = $price.val();
    var calcPerc = (discount * 100 / price);
    $percentage.val(calcPerc);
  }
});

function getVal() {
  console.log($("#select").val());
  console.log($("#select option:selected").attr('price'));
}

getVal();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="property_id" onchange='getVal()' id='select'>
   <option value="1" price="15000">Property A</option>
   <option value="2" price="21000">Property B</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$("#select").change(function() {


  alert($("option:selected", this).attr("data-price"))

}).change()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="property_id" id='select'>
   <option value="1" data-price="15000">Property A</option>
   <option value="2" data-price="21000">Property B</option>
</select>
```

1. Use `this` context
2. use `data-*` attribute since price is not a valid attribute

Comment: Could you please provide an example where using *"invalid"* attributes would cause `jQuery` not to read them using `.attr()` method?

Comment: there is a reason why there is valid and invalid and i think i dont need to expand on those

Answer (score 1):

`.val()` is a jQuery method that gives you the `value` attribute of an `<input>`.

Example:

```
 <input value="some-value" id="demo" />
 $("#demo").val(); 
 // will return "some-value"
```

It does not give you the value of an attribute of an `<input>`. Semantically it might be a small difference, but it's an important one.

Example:

```
 <input value="some-value" id="demo" price="12345" />
 $price = $("[price]").val(); 
 // will also return "some-value", 
 // it doesn't matter you called the var `$price` or that you used
 // the `price` attribute to select it from DOM
```

In order to get the `price` custom attribute value of any element, considering your example, you should use:

```
 <input price="1234" />
 $(this).attr('price');
 // will return "1234"
```

***** In all examples above `$(this)` is supposed to be a `jQuery` wrapper around the element outlined before it.